# Do you need a minyan for Kol Nidrei?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, minyan

Is it necessary to have a minyan in order to recite Kol Nidrei on Erev Yom Kippur?

If no, then do you need at least three  men, as is necessary for Hataras Nedarim?

Answer (score 8):

No, not according to the answer on [this](http://dinonline.org/2011/10/05/yizkor-and-kol-nidrei-in-private/) site:

> Although it is preferable to join a minyan where this is possible, both Kol Nidrei and Yizkor can be recited in private. The reason for this is that neither are considered a “davar shebikdusha” that requires a minyan.

Comment: It would have been nice had the author included a source to his claims. I wonder why it would not need even three men as with Hataras Nedarim. I have edited the question to include this possibility.